# What is the sum of the given special series?any specific formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1^n$+$2^n$+$3^n$+$\dots$+$m^n$.
$(m,n\in\mathcal N)$

$m,n\ge2$

Comment: Keyword: Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: ok i got my answer. thanks :)